get connected lan hosts via arp and output on single line
I'm using the following nmap command
nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24 | awk '{print $1}'`| awk '/Nmap scan report for/{print " "$5,$6;}/MAC 
Address:/{print $3;}'

which outputs
box1.lan (192.168.1.119)
00:0E:C7:82:48:10
box2.lan (192.168.1.189)
00:E0:4F:68:01:14

how do i get it to output as
00:0E:C7:82:48:10 box1.lan 192.168.1.119
00:E0:4F:68:01:14 box2.lan 192.168.1.189


If you only care about ARP, why do you run a lengthy nmap and not ip neigh?

I don't think ip neigh does hostnames does it?
